# How to simplify nginx error log?

Tags: nginx

I want to simplify nginx error log but without success.
I'm executing in index.php this:

```
error_log('abc');
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
2016/08/22 16:11:57 [error] 5267#0: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: abc" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.12, server: domain.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com", referrer: "http://domain.com/"
```

while watching nginx error file:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

I have tried to edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf + added

```
log_format vhosts 'test';
```

in http{ section but error message is still same.
I would like to get only "abc" in error.log file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`log_format` is for `access_log`. Something like:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log | awk '{print $12}'
```

may do the trick but only if "abc" is a non-whitespace string.

Comment: "log_format" for error_log does not exist?

Comment: No, log_format sets the format style for access_log only

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simplify error log like this.

nginx receives the error information via FastCGI interface used between nginx and application server software (PHP in this case).

`2016/08/22 16:11:57 [error] 5267#0: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr:` is the part nginx writes to `error.log` to indicate timestamp and that the following error message comes from the FastCGI interface.

`"PHP message: abc"` is the message sent by PHP itself.

`while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.12, server: domain.com, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com", referrer: "http://domain.com/"` is added by nginx to indicate other information about the error.

You can use PHP `error_log()` function's `$destination` parameter to write errors to a log file when the `message_type` is set to 3. However, that might contain other text than the exact test. In that case, you can always open a new file and write to it via PHP. Maybe you want to implement your own logging function for that.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Suggestions are good and acceptable but right now I wanna just to use nginx error log. I used php error_log() function I used to improved my question, on the end I want to simplify real errors which are showing in nginx error.log, for custom login I have custom log function.